# Web scrape site where I need to login

Tags: c#, web-scraping, htmlunit

I was thinking to have a console application that will scrape a site where it need to be logined.
I was thinking to use htmlUnit (open for other suggestion if you know better once) to post the data to the site. But is there any security failure with that?
Post the authentication is what I'm thinking on. I don't know that mutch about sniffing. But what if any sniffing on my server, those will see my authentication?

Is it better to stay logined after it scraped? Or is it better to logout and login x hours later to scrape again?

Is this even any "problem"? I was thinking to have my site that shows the data on the same server as the  scrape service. So perhaps someone start look at my site and then see my scrape request.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking and it doesn't seem to be a concrete problem that you are having? Maybe this site isn't the right place for you to ask this anyways?

Comment: Ok you're maybe right. No it was more a security question if someone sniffing when I post the data. Because I can't send it encrypted.